# How to avoid roll in SceneKit camera controlled by Core Motion?

Tags: ios, camera, scenekit, quaternions, core-motion

I'm setting my SceneKit camera to the current `CMDeviceMotion` attitude using the [CMDeviceMotion extension](https://gist.github.com/travisnewby/96ee1ac2bc2002f1d480) described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33695442/235297):

```
func deviceDidMove(motion: CMDeviceMotion?, error: NSError?) {
    if let motion = motion {
        let orientation = motion.gaze(atOrientation: UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation)
        cameraNode.orientation = orientation
    }
}
```

This works beautifully, however, I'd like to block the rotation (roll) and only allow the camera to turn around (yaw) and pitch.

I tried to convert the quaternion back to Euler angles and simply leave roll at 0:

```
cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(
            x: orientation.pitch(),
            y: orientation.yaw(),
            z: 0)
```

However, this works for only one half of the yaw movement. For the other half, the camera is turned upside down. I suspect this is a Gimbal Lock issue involving Euler angles.

Quaternions are a bit like black magic for me, but is there a way to remove the roll component directly on the quaternion level so I can avoid Euler angles?

Comment: Have you had any luck figuring this out?

Comment: No. :( I'd post it here then.

Comment: I think there's two ways to think about this, but I'm no expert. One is to filter out the axis of movement you don't want from the CM data. The other is to do (as you suggest) a "gimbal lock" that prevents movement in a given axis.

Comment: I've seen this result achieved with CM, but don't know how it was done.

Comment: is this any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576484/calculating-lean-angle-with-core-motion

Comment: I know... you've probably seen this... but just in case you haven't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282543/mapping-physical-360-rotation-to-scenekit

Comment: And, if you can get his attention, I'm almost certain this guy will know a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/users/957768/rickster